# Eclipse: Add GroupBy Menu to Custom Marker View

Tags: eclipse

I am developing an Eclipse plugin and I have created my own custom marker view for my own custom markers. Now I want to add a GroupBy-menu to the view like the GroupBy-menu of the Eclipse Problems-view where I can group markers by type, location etc. I know that I have to use the markerGrouping of the markerSupport-Extension point but I don't know how it works.